# Как сделать button с такими еффектом?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать button с такими еффектом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как вариант задать тень:

```
<button>
</button>

button{
  width: 100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: yellow;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px -8px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px -8px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px -8px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Нужное положение и цвет настроите сами, как нужно